# When to use read() or read(byte[]) or BufferedInputStream?

Tags: java

When to use `read()` byte by byte and when to use `read(byte[])` array of byte. As I think reading `read(byte[])` array is always better. then can you give me example where to use `read()` byte by byte OR `read(byte[])` array of byte. OR BufferedInputStream.?

Same these for Reader.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can't afford to allocate an input buffer (very constrained memory), so you process input byte by byte.

All that `BufferedInputStream` really does is it manages a `byte[]` buffer for you and calls `read(byte[])` behind the scenes. You can then call `read()` one byte at a time without worrying about the overhead of system calls.

If you just want to read N bytes and store them, allocating a `byte[N]` and passing it to `read(byte[])` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Sometimes? Example? and `read(byte[])` and `BufferedInputStream` are same? `You can then call read() one byte at a time without worrying about the overhead of system calls.` can you explain please? how?

Answer (score 0):

This is something I was considering a little while back and the decisions I made might be of help to you. So, here are my 2 cents.

In certain cases, say you want to read in a million bytes of data. Passing an array of a these bytes would require a sequential allocation of a million bytes. This can be quite problematic in constrained environments. So, you would be better off reading byte-by-byte and then process them based on the requirements.

`BufferedInputStream`, `ByteBuffer` and the sort, just help you manage access to the byte array in an easier and more streamlined fashion.